# Integrate sonarqube with cloudbuild

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sonarqube, google-cloud-build

I am trying use sonarqube with cloudbuild but i am getting error "Your project contains .java files, please provide compiled classes with sonar.java.binaries property"
my cloubuild.yaml file are below.

```
 - id: 'Sonarqube' 
name: 'gcr.io/{project-id}/testt:latest'
args:
- '-Dsonar.host.url={url}'
- '-Dsonar.login={login}'
- '-Dsonar.projectKey=m{key}'
- '-Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true'
- '-Dsonar.sources=.'
```

- id: 'build your instance'
  name: 'maven:3-jdk-8'
  entrypoint: mvn
  args: ['clean','package']

Comment: What's the content of this container `gcr.io/{project-id}/testt:latest`?

Comment: it containe sonarqube image https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/sonarqube

Comment: Did you have launch compilation stages before running sonarqube? I mean do you have a target dir in your workspace?

Comment: yes i compiled it, and target dir is created. My code is in java8 but sonarqube image uses java11 could that be an issue?

Comment: Can you try with this `- '-Dsonar.sources=.'/target`?

Comment: Yes, it worked by specifying target path thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear.  Don't change any of the existing properties, but add a setting for "sonar.java.binaries=target".

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, and in relation with the error, sonarqube use only compiled files. Use the `./target` dir (which contains .class compiled files) instead of the root dir (which contains not compiled Java files.